# 2 responsive background images, one div inside the other

Tags: css, background-image, responsive-images

I have the following `div` with a background image and another `div` with a background image. They need to stay together in the same configuration when responsive. I have an auto scroll on hover the inside image. All done with CSS. However, I'm using padding to align the 2 together but it is making both images to small and I want them to fill the column. Does anyone have a better suggestion as to how to do this? Please take a look at what I  did.

[https://jsfiddle.net/517Design/gukbnzf8/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/517Design/gukbnzf8/3/)

Comment: Your fiddle link is not working, please check the url

Comment: Hi thanks for looking. This link is working fine for me

http://jsfiddle.net/517Design/gukbnzf8/3/